# How do I assign strings to resultset values in a loop?

Tags: java, sql, eclipse

I have a SQL statement that includes meta_key values.  When I run through the Result Set using while/next, the values are properly displayed.  What I would like to do is to assign each value to a uniquely named or numbered string for use in a subsequent statement to post these values to a website.

I have everything working except for assigning the resulting values to strings....I'm sure that I'm doing this like a rank beginner, so I apologize in advance.

```
try {
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                            "jdbc:mysql://sftp.databaseengine.com:3306/table", "user",
                            "password");
                    String getcomp = "SELECT DISTINCT wpgc.user_id, wpgc.status, wpgc.content_id, wpu.meta_key,\r\n"
                            + "                CASE wpu.meta_value WHEN 'm' THEN 'MALE' WHEN 'f' THEN 'FEMALE'\r\n"
                            + "                                    WHEN 'Louisiana' THEN 'LA' ELSE wpu.meta_value END AS '1',\r\n"
                            + "                wpu.user_id,  wpgc.timestamp \r\n"
                            + "  FROM wp_grassblade_completions AS wpgc\r\n"
                            + "  JOIN wp_usermeta AS wpu ON wpgc.user_id = wpu.user_id\r\n"
                            + "  WHERE wpgc.user_id = ? \r\n"
                            + "  AND wpu.meta_key IN ('mepr_full_name', 'mepr_address', 'mepr_city', 'mepr_state',\r\n"
                            + "                       'mepr_zip_code', 'mepr_home_phone_with_area_code',\r\n"
                            + "                       'mepr_drivers_license_or_id', 'mepr_id_state',\r\n"
                            + "                       'mepr_Last_four_of_social_security_number',\r\n"
                            + "                       'mepr_date_of_birth_mmddyyyy', 'mepr_sex_mf', 'mepr_height',\r\n"
                            + "                       'mepr_weight')\r\n";
    PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(getcomp);
                    pst.setString(1, user_id);

                    ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
                    
                    while (rs.next()) {

                        for (int i = 0; i < 13; ++i) {
                            String value = rs.getString(5);
                            if i = 1 {}

                            System.out.println(i + " column " + (value));
                            

                            rs.next();

                        }

                    }
                }

                catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Exception on " + user_id);
                }

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Put them inside a `List`. Or a `Map`, if you need to maintain the link between `i` and `value`

Comment: Thanks so much for the guidance!  I appreciate it.

Not sure how I would refer to the navigable map entries, but I'm reading up on it :)

Answer (score 1):

## `Map`

A `Map` is a collection of key-value pairings. A `NavigableMap` ( or `SortedMap`) maintains the keys in sorted order, if you care about that.

Search to learn more, as this has been covered many many times already.

```
NavigableMap< Integer , String > map = new TreeMap<>() ;
map.put( 1 , "Alice" ) ;
map.put( 2 , "Bob" ) ;
```

In your case:

```
map.put( i , value ) ;
```

And learn about auto-boxing in Java, converting between primitives and objects.

## `record`

As an alternative to using a map, you could instantiate objects from a custom class you define to hold your retrieved values.

In Java 16, defining a class is much briefer, if the main purpose is to communicate data transparently and immutably. Simply declare the type and name of each member field. The compiler implicitly creates the constructor, getters, `equals` and `hashCode`, and `toString`.

```
record Pair ( int id, String value ) {}
```

Usage.

```
List< Pair > list = new ArrayList<>() ;
…
list.add ( new Pair( i , value ) ) ;
…
```

Of course you would invent names of class and fields to be more descriptive.

## Counting rows

I’m not sure as I did not study your code, but you don’t want a `for` loop in your result set processing. For a counter, use this:

```
int i = 0 ;
while (rs.next()) {
    i ++ ;
    …
 }
```

Or even better, generate the 1, 2, 3 sequence of numbers dynamically in your SQL as an extra column defined in your query. Search Stack Overflow or sister site DBA.StackExchange.com to learn more.